# Resuming the HTTP Download of a File and HTTP compression

Tags: python, qt, http, http-headers, pyqt

the file I want to download is 1000000 bytes uncompressed, the downloads was interrupted when 5000 bytes compressed data was transmitted .If I want to Resuming the HTTP Download ,I wonder what value of the HTTP Range header should be ,“bytes=5000-“ or “bytes= size(downloadedPart) -”? why ?

Answer (score 1):

Up to me it should be

```
bytes=5000-
```

so you instruct HTTP server to start FROM specified location and send you everything after specified offset